# Closing session in neo4j OGM

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Should we open and close a session in code while using neo4j ogm.

Using sessionFactory.openSession() to open a session.

Do we need to explicitly close the session.

Answer (score 1):

No what's in the session is automatically cleaned when the session is garbage collected.

Be careful however to correctly close transactions.